# how to install python 3.5 in wine?

Tags: wine, python3

How to install python 3.5 in wine? The installation guides for installation of python 2.7 or 3.4 makes use of python msi installer but there is no msi installer available for python 3.5. What should I do?

Comment: All executable installers can be found at [Python Download Page](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-35)

Comment: and then should I simply run "wine python-3.5.2-amd64.exe" ?

Comment: I wonder why you want to install python in wine... you do know python is installed in Ubuntu by default?

Comment: I never installed python in wine. So, I'm clueless in this. Also, it seems to be pointless to install python in Wine when you have pre-installed in Ubuntu. What makes you install that in wine?

Comment: I want to make cross platform python exe in ubuntu.

Comment: Yes, python is required in wine to use pyinstaller to convert scripts into an .exe file, so does anyone have the answer?